# Spring MVC 3.0 InternalResourceViewResolver custom view file

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a view resolver:

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="order"><value>1</value></property>
</bean>
```

And a method:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello_world.html")
public ModelAndView index() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("test");
    return mav;
}
```

I would like to render /WEB-INF/jsp/test.jsp but it always try to render /WEB-INF/jsp/hello_world.jsp

How can I define custon view page inside index()?

Thank you

Comment: What file contents does end up in webbrowser? The one of `test.jsp` or `hello_world.jsp` ? Spring is likely doing a forward and you apparently expected its path to be reflected in the browser address bar.

Comment: hello_world.jsp, but i need test.jsp, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView instead of org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView! ;^)

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping("/hello_world.html")
public ModelAndView index() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/test");
    return mav;
}
```

Instead of "test", do "/test"